# ¿Como abrir un P:dialog desde p:ajax?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

necesito abrir una Dialog, para confirmar si desea guardar o no los cambios, ya tengo ambas vistas, solo necesito, que al activarse la celda, como cellEdit, antes de guardar este muestre el dialog.

Este es la etiqueta Ajax.
`<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{beansDefiniciones.onCellEdit}" update=":form1:growl" />`

Este es el dialog:

````
                        <p:outputLabel value="¿ Desea guardar los cambios ?"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Si" actionListener="#{beansDefiniciones.onCellEdit}" onclick="PF('EnvConfirm').hide()"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="No" onclick="PF('EnvConfirm').hide()"/>
                    </p:dialog> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Probaste con

```
 onstart="PF('tu_dialog').show();" dentro de <p:ajax
```